# Can I use abstract methods to import file-specific formatting of (Python) pandas data?

Tags: python, pandas, methods, format, python-module

I have a class `FileSet` with a method `_process_series`, which contains a bunch of `if`-`elif` blocks doing `filetag`-specific formatting of different `pandas.Series`:

```
    elif filetag == "EntityA":
        ps[filetag+"_Id"] = str(ps[filetag+"_Id"]).strip()
        ps[filetag+"_DateOfBirth"] = str(pd.to_datetime(ps[filetag+"_DateOfBirth"]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).strip()
        ps[filetag+"_FirstName"] = str(ps[filetag+"_FirstName"]).strip().capitalize()
        ps[filetag+"_LastName"] = str(ps[filetag+"_LastName"]).strip().capitalize()
        ps[filetag+"_Age"] = relativedelta(datetime.today(), datetime.strptime(ps[filetag+"_DateOfBirth"], "%Y-%m-%d")).years
        return ps
```

I'd like to define an abstract `format` method in the class and keep these blocks of formatting in separate modules that are imported when `_process_series` is called for a given `filetag`.  Forgive the pseudo-code, but something like:

```
for tag in filetag:
    from my_formatters import tag+'_formatter' as fmt
    ps = self.format(pandas_series, fmt)
    return ps
```

And the module would contain the formatting block:

```
# my_formatters.EntityA_formatter
    ps[filetag+"_Id"] = str(ps[filetag+"_Id"]).strip()
    ps[filetag+"_DateOfBirth"] = str(pd.to_datetime(ps[filetag+"_DateOfBirth"]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).strip()
    ps[filetag+"_FirstName"] = str(ps[filetag+"_FirstName"]).strip().capitalize()
    ps[filetag+"_LastName"] = str(ps[filetag+"_LastName"]).strip().capitalize()
    ps[filetag+"_Age"] = relativedelta(datetime.today(), datetime.strptime(ps[filetag+"_DateOfBirth"], "%Y-%m-%d")).years
    return ps
```

Comment: Sorry, what's the question exactly?

Comment: could you clarify your question? Do you get any special errors?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want your filetag formatters to be modules specifically?  I think it would be more common to just make them functions or classes if they need to store a bit of state.  You _could_ have some sort of complex "registering" logic, but you could also just hard code the mapping from filetags to formatters in `FileSet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `globals` with asterisk:

```
from my_formatters import *

for tag in filetag:
    fmt = globals()[tag + '_formatter']
    ps = self.format(pandas_series, fmt)
    return ps
```

I converted your pseudocode to real code.

`globals` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals):

> Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol table. This is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a function or method, this is the module where it is defined, not the module from which it is called).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function in it's own .py file and import it. If you create the same function in each file you can then call it.

here is f1.py:

```
def gimme():
    return 'format 1'
```

here is f2.py:

```
def gimme():
    return 'format 2'
```

Then you main file:

```
module_names = ['f1','f2']

for module_name in module_names:
    import_test = __import__(module_name)
    result = import_test.gimme()
    result = import_test.gimme()
    print(result)
```

Which gives the output:

```
format 1
format 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your psuedocode could be made into real code like so:

```
import my_formatters

for tag in filetag:
    fmt = getattr(my_formatters, tag + '_formatter')
    ps = self.format(pandas_series, fmt)
    return ps
```